# Using T-SQL and Joins, display a hierarchy of employees in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, inner-join

I would like to generate a table like this:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level | PersonName | empid | ManagerID | Code   | ManagerName  |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1     | BigBoss    | 1     | null      | 00     | null         |
| 2     | Executive1 | 2     | 1         | 0001   | BigBoss      |
| 2     | Executive2 | 3     | 1         | 0002   | BigBoss      |
| 3     | Manager1   | 4     | 2         | 000101 | Executive1   |
| 3     | Manager2   | 5     | 2         | 000102 | Executive1   |
| 3     | Manager3   | 6     | 3         | 000201 | Executive2   |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So, as you can see a subordinate has 2 more digits in his code as compared to his manager and the `Code` determines the hierarchy. Sometimes during reorganization, employee's codes are not updated immediately, so the coding becomes inconsistent generating an error in the table like so:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level | PersonName | empid | ManagerID | Code   | ManagerName  |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1     | BigBoss    | 1     | null      | 00     | null         |
| 2     | Executive1 | 2     | 1         | 0001   | BigBoss      |
| 2     | Executive2 | 3     | 1         | 0002   | BigBoss      |
| 3     | Manager1   | 4     | 2         | 000101 | Executive1   |
| 3     | Manager2   | 5     | 2         | 000102 | Executive1   |
| 3     | Manager3   | 6     | 3         | 000201 | Executive2   |
| 3     | Manager4   | 7     | 99        | 000202 | WrongManager |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So, I would like to add a condition that checks that if a person's  manager  id exists as  the  id in the level above. For instance in level 3, Manager 4's manager  id is 99. The manager id, 99 does not exist as a person's id in level 2, therefore it should not  be included.

This is my attempt at the code:

```
select 
    1 as level
    ,reportfor.preferredname + ' ' + reportfor.surname as PersonName
    ,id
    ,null as ManagerID
    ,emp.code as Code
    ,null as ManagerName
from d_edr edr
    inner join o_training_courses crs on crs.sap_course_num=edr.course_id
    inner join employees emp on emp.empid=edr.empid
    inner join employees reportfor on reportfor.code = '00'
group by 
    ,reportfor.preferredname + ' ' + reportfor.surname 
    ,id
    ,emp.code 
union 
select 
    2 as level
    ,reportfor.preferredname + ' ' + reportfor.surname as PersonName
    ,id
    ,emp.mgrid as ManagerID
    ,emp.code as Code
    ,mgr.preferredname + ' ' + mgr.surname as ManagerName
from d_edr edr
    inner join o_training_courses crs on crs.sap_course_num=edr.course_id
    inner join employees emp on emp.empid=edr.empid
    inner join employees reportfor on reportfor.code LIKE '00__'
    inner join employees mgr on mgr.empid=reportfor.mgrid
group by 
    ,reportfor.preferredname + ' ' + reportfor.surname
    ,id
    ,emp.mgrid
    ,emp.code
    ,mgr.preferredname + ' ' + mgr.surname
union 
select 
    3 as level
    ,reportfor.preferredname + ' ' + reportfor.surname as PersonName
    ,id
    ,emp.mgrid as ManagerID
    ,emp.code as Code
    ,mgr.preferredname + ' ' + mgr.surname as ManagerName
from d_edr edr
    inner join o_training_courses crs on crs.sap_course_num=edr.course_id
    inner join employees emp on emp.empid=edr.empid
    inner join employees reportfor on reportfor.code LIKE '00____'
    inner join employees mgr on mgr.empid=reportfor.mgrid
group by 
    ,reportfor.preferredname + ' ' + reportfor.surname
    ,id
    ,emp.mgrid
    ,emp.code
    ,mgr.preferredname + ' ' + mgr.surname
```

I was hoping that this line of code would take care of it, but it doesn't

```
inner join employees mgr on mgr.empid=reportfor.mgrid
```

The definition of the employee table is:

```
empid = employee id
preferred name = first name
surname = last name 
code = hierarchy code
mgrid = manager id
```

Comment: I just need to know, But why the code if you already have the ManagerID? and what will happen if you have a level 4 and 5. Are you going to union for every level?

Comment: With regard to invalid `ManagerID` values, why not just add a self-referencing foreign key to enforce referential integrity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CTE

```
WITH OrgChart AS    
(    
    SELECT  1 as level
            ,emp.preferredname + ' ' + emp.surname as PersonName
            ,id
            ,null as ManagerID
            ,emp.code as Code
            ,null as ManagerName
    FROM d_edr edr
        inner join o_training_courses crs on crs.sap_course_num=edr.course_id
        inner join employees emp on emp.empid=edr.empid
    WHERE emp.code = '00'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT OrgChart.level + 1 level
            ,emp.preferredname + ' ' + emp.surname as PersonName
            ,id
            ,null as ManagerID
            ,emp.code as Code
            ,null as ManagerName
    FROM d_edr edr
        inner join o_training_courses crs on crs.sap_course_num=edr.course_id
        inner join employees emp on emp.empid=edr.empid
        INNER JOIN OrgChart ON edr.empid = OrgChart.empid
    WHERE emp.code != '00'

)
SELECT *
FROM OrgChart;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the answer you are looking for, but it might be an alternative solution for you to select your data instead of the UNION for each Level.

```
WITH Employee_hierarchy (Level, PersonName, EmpID, ManagerID, Code, ManagerName) AS
(

      SELECT 1 AS Level, base.PersonName, base.EmpID, base.mgrid, Code, convert(varchar(50), Null) ManagerName
      FROM employees base
      WHERE base.mgrid is null
      UNION all

      SELECT LEVEL + 1 AS Level, child.PersonName,  child.EmpID, child.mgrid, child.Code, eh.PersonName
      FROM employees child
      inner join Employee_hierarchy eh on child.mgrid = eh.EmpID
)     

Select * from Employee_hierarchy
```

If you want to read up about Common Table Expressions or CTE. Here is a link
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx